# Difference between MappingSqlQuery or RowMapper and which one is recommended to perform select operation?

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I want to perform a SELECT operation. When I searched on google I got **MappingSqlQuery** and **RowMapper** examples. I am confused about which one is best, performance-wise, to perform a SELECT operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MappingSqlQuery` actually will create a `RowMapper` behind the scenes and use `JdbcTemplate` to [query the result](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a89e716cc71a8741385a0224b5d7eb7ce009e11a/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/object/SqlQuery.java#L110):

```
public List<T> execute(@Nullable Object[] params, @Nullable Map<?, ?> context) throws DataAccessException {
    validateParameters(params);
    RowMapper<T> rowMapper = newRowMapper(params, context);
    return getJdbcTemplate().query(newPreparedStatementCreator(params), rowMapper);
}
```

So from a performance point of view, directly using `RowMapper` with `JDBCTemplate` should be a little little bit faster than `MappingSqlQuery`. But it is micro performance differences which you will not feel.

Which one to use depends on your preferences. For MappingSqlQuery, you have to create a new class for every query. For `RowMapper` with `JdbcTemplate`, you just need to create a single class for a group of queries that do similar things. For a system that has a lot of queries, I would choose the latter one as I don't like to create so many `MappingSqlQuery` classes.